# SPNEGO authentication in Phantom

Tags: phantomjs

Experimenting with Phantomjs to scrape some information from a vendor application our company uses.  When I open the page and render it, I can see that the only output is the message

> SPNEGO authentication is not supported on this client.

I had seen that message in Firefox before, and the solution was to add the host to the trusted uris.  That's great for FF, but in the context of a phantomjs script, is there a way to declare a site as trusted?

UPDATE: Tried the command-line parameters per Artjom's suggestion but no difference.

Comment: What happens when you run phantomjs with the `--web-security=false`, `--local-to-remote-url-access=true` or `--ignore-ssl-errors=true`  [options](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference) and combinations thereof?

Comment: @Artjom - Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately no difference.  Updated question with the results for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this protocol is implemented in PhantomJS. PhantomJS is built on top of QtWebKit. I found an old [Aurora issue](https://code.google.com/p/arora/issues/detail?id=401). Aurora is also based on QtWebKit.

If you search for `SPNEGO` or `kerberos` in the [phantomjs repo](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs), you don't find much. Searching for `negotiate` shows only some constants, but no actual implementation.

Comment: I had looked through the source as well and nothing stood out.  I was hoping I just overlooked it.  Thanks.